# Multiplying values from a string column in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a column with land dimensions in Pandas. It looks like this:

```
df.LotSizeDimensions.value_counts(dropna=False)

40.00X150.00                                                                                                 2
57.00X130.00                                                                                                 2
27.00X117.00                                                                                                 2
63.00X135.00                                                                                                 2
37.00X108.00                                                                                                 2
65.00X134.00                                                                                                 2
57.00X116.00                                                                                                 2
33x124x67x31x20x118                                                                                          1
55.00X160.00                                                                                                 1
63.00X126.00                                                                                                 1
36.00X105.50                                                                                                 1
```

In rows where there is only one X, I would like to create a separate column that would multiply the values. In columns where there is more than one X, I would like to return a zero. This is the code I came up with

```
def dimensions_split(df: pd.DataFrame):
    df.LotSizeDimensions = df.LotSizeDimensions.str.strip()
    df.LotSizeDimensions = df.LotSizeDimensions.str.upper()
    df.LotSizeDimensions = df.LotSizeDimensions.str.strip('`"M')
    
    if df.LotSizeDimensions.count('X') > 1
         return 0
    df['LotSize'] = map(int(df.LotSizeDimensions.str.split("X", 1).str[0])*int(df.LotSizeDimensions.str.split("X", 1).str[1]))
```

This is coming back with the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

I would also like to add a line where if there are any non-numeric characters other than X, return a zero.

Comment: Instead of describing your data in words, please post a small dataframe that we can copy-paste and work with. Include the desired result for that sample data.

Comment: to convert data type you need to use df[column].astype(int) or pd.to numeric rather than casting the python int class o your data frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is first stripping and convert to upper column `LotSizeDimensions` to `Series` and then use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for `DataFrame` and then multiple columns if there is only one `X` else is returned `0`:

```
s = df.LotSizeDimensions.str.strip('`"M ').str.upper()

df1 = s.str.split('X', expand=True).astype(float)
#general data
#df1 = s.str.split('X', expand=True).apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))
df['LotSize'] = np.where(s.str.count('X').eq(1), df1[0] * df1[1], 0)
print (df)
      LotSizeDimensions  LotSize
0          40.00X150.00   6000.0
1          57.00X130.00   7410.0
2          27.00X117.00   3159.0
3          37.00X108.00   3996.0
4          63.00X135.00   8505.0
5          65.00X134.00   8710.0
6          57.00X116.00   6612.0
7   33x124x67x31x20x118      0.0
8          55.00X160.00   8800.0
9          63.00X126.00   7938.0
10         36.00X105.50   3798.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I get this using list comprehension:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['40.00X150.00','57.00X130.00',
'27.00X117.00',
'37.00X108.00',
'63.00X135.00' ,
'65.00X134.00'  ,
'57.00X116.00'   ,
'33x124x67x31x20x118',
'55.00X160.00',
'63.00X126.00',
'36.00X105.50'])
df[1] = [float(str_data.strip().split("X")[0])*float(str_data.strip().split("X")[1]) if len(str_data.strip().split("X"))==2 else None for str_data in df[0]]
```